# Alternate code for Throws IOException

Tags: java, exception, ioexception

What changes do I need to make in the code If I remove the line "throws IOException"??

```
import java.io.*;
class Buffered_class{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
                    throws IOException // remove this line 
    {
        char c;
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.print("Enter characters, 'q' to quit");
        do{
           c= (char)br.read();
           System.out.println(" you entered : " + c );
       }while(c !='q'); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Try something, then come back. More info: [Lesson: Exceptions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/)

Comment: Why are you throwing IOException ?

Comment: @AbdullahShaikh using `BufferedReader#read` throws `IOException`.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I know that. I wanted OP to answer/know that and then understand why to catch it. :)

Comment: @AbdullahShaikh there are plenty resources, and the official resource about Exception handling. We cannot do more than hope for OP to learn something on its own.

Answer (score 2):

You need to catch the exception

```
import java.io.*;    
class Buffered_class{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
       char c;
       try{
           BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
           System.out.print("Enter characters, 'q' to quit");        
           do{
               c= (char)br.read();
               System.out.println(" you entered : " + c );

           }while(c !='q'); 
       }catch(IOException e){
             // do something
       }finally{
           br.close();
   }
}
```

Comment: The problem with this code is that you're not closing the resources used by the `BufferedReader`. Remember to **always** call `close`.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza you're right!